# Difference between else if and else{if}

Tags: performance, if-statement, readability

is there an actual difference between these two?

First:

```
if(condition1){
    // code 1
}else if(condition2){
    // code 2
}else if(condition3){
    // code 3
}else if(condition4){
    // code 4
}else if(condition5){
    // code 5
}else{
    // code 6
}
```

Second

```
if(condition1){
    // code 1
}else{
    if(condition2){
        // code 2
    }else{
        if(condition3){
            // code 3
        }else{
            if(condition4){
                // code 4
            }else{
                if(condition5){
                    // code 5
                }else{
                    // code 6
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm asking as far as performance or better practices or even readability.

BTW: I know there is the `switch` sentence, but I'm just curious. :)

Comment: Which language are you talking about?

Comment: Question would have made sense with a language with a construct something like elif. As it is your examples only differ by whitespace

Comment: @JanBerktold not a special one, I know could be differences in compiler, I use to write code in PHP, JS, JAVA, C++, and PYTHON. So I tried to write with no special syntax to make the question more general.

Comment: pyramid of doom! if each of those conditions are relatively long, and/or the number of conditions double or even tripple, you end up with horizontal scrolling (or word wrapping) in your editor which may (er, will) affect readability. you really shouldn't look at it from a performance point of view unless you're actually dealing with a performance sensitive case or problem.

Answer (score 3):

The braces mark a compound statement or block, i.e multiple statements. In your example there's only one statement so the braces can be skipped, that's it. Difference has no practical value except to those who have big arguments over indentation.

Answer (score 0):

One can not say that using one way over the other one is more efficient in every single language.

However, in the case that there are any differences in the language you are using, then those differences should be unnoticeable.